# Inherited field in derived class - both solutions appear lame

Tags: java, oop, inheritance

I have some class `X` with the field `A` in it. It is a final field, initialized in constructor. Now I have a derived class `Y` where this field must always be an instance of `B`, a class that is derived from `A`. The problem, the class `Y` needs to call a number specific methods that are only available on the class B but not on its ancestor, `A`.

I see several solutions:

1. Reuse the field of the type `A`, inherited from `X`, and inside the class `Y`, cast `A` to `B`. This makes my code full of nasty type casts.
2. Add another field of the type `B`. Now there are no typecasts but we have two fields of slightly different type that must always hold the same value - also does not feel good.
3. Add all methods that `B` provides also to `A`, throw `NotImplementedException`. This adds some strange methods that knowingly make no sense in that class.

Which is the most right way to deal with this field? Or maybe some other, better exists? I do not think this is very language specific but must be doable in Java I am using.

Comment: Option #2 seems fine to me

Comment: Also, Option #1 might be a good solution. Depending on what "full of" means, YMMV

Comment: Shouldn't X be defined as `X<T extends A>`, and Y be `Y extends X<B>`? You wouldn't have any type cast.

Comment: Agree. This seems really an idea.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The X type should probably be a generic type:

```
public class X<T extends A> {

    protected T a;

    public X(T a) {
        this.a = a;
    }
}

public clas Y extends X<B> {

    public Y(B b) {
        super(b);
    }

    public void foo() {
        // here, this.a is of type B, without any type cast.
    }
}
```

Comment: Only applicable if `A` can/should anticipate `B`'s existence. But then, it's a nice solution that Java _should_ be able to do _without_ generics.

Comment: Yes, of course. If A can't be modified and is not generic, you need type casts.

Answer (score 2):

The only sane solution I can think of is a variation of #1: add to class `Y` a getter method that returns the field cast to the type `B`, and access the field only through this getter. That will only require one cast, and as a beneficial side effect it will also document which parts of the code require that the field be actually a `B`.

Answer (score 2):

Solution #1 is the most correct way, in my opinion. If you *know* that an object is of a specific class, there's nothing wrong with casting it to that class. It'd be wrong if you were making assumptions while doing this, but this is not an assumption, according to what you're saying. Maybe make a getter method that simply casts the underlying field to the correct type and be done with it? That way, you'll only have to cast once (per subclass).

Solution #2 will cause elusive runtime errors if the fields somehow cease being properly up-to-date with each other. This seriously sounds like the worst solution.

Solution #3 still feels like bad software design. If a method exists and it's not in an abstract class and you are not in a prototyping phase, then that method should be implemented. Otherwise, you're probably just planting unnecessary traps for the user (of the class) by giving it a misleading interface.